# Generator Ordering Causing Infinite Recursion in For Comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension, scalacheck

In the following codes, the change in ordering of generators in for-comprehension is causing an infinite recursion.

The following code gives infinite recursion

```scala
lazy val genHeap: Gen[H] = oneOf(const(empty), for {
   heap <- genHeap 
   value <- arbitrary[Int] 
} yield insert(value, heap))
```

while the following code works

```scala
lazy val genHeap: Gen[H] = oneOf(const(empty), for {
   value <- arbitrary[Int] 
   heap <- genHeap 
} yield insert(value, heap))
```

The above functions are defined in an abstract class called `QuickCheck`.The code is called as follows

```scala
object quickcheck extends QuickCheck
quickcheck.genHeap
```

I think, the reason is that in the first case, `genHeap` is equivalent to

```scala
oneOf(const(empty), 
      genHeap flatMap (heap => arbitrary[Int] map (value => insert(value, heap)))
```

Since `oneOf` takes generators by value, the inner genHeap is also executed, which causes the infinite recursion.

In the second case, `genHeap` is inside the flatMap, so it need not be executed until the function call.

Am I on the right track with this explanation?

Comment: What are `genHeap` and `arbitrary[Int]` types?

Comment: Both are scalacheck generators. arbitrary[Int] is a random int generator. genHeap is supposed to be a random heap generator.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829293/scalacheck-arbitrary-implicits-and-recursive-generators

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies my confusion. Flagging this question as duplicate.